# How to access number of tests passed, failed and total number of tests in declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have requirement to find number of passed tests, failed tests  and total number of tests executed in declarative pipeline, so that I can put some condition and do my next actions. 
I checked http://localhost:8080/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild by thinking there will be some variable for this. Not found any.

Comment: Surely that's going to depend on what exactly is running those tests and where it outputs that information? Are you generating summary files? Just printing the result to the console?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am injecting test results into Jenkins build once test case execution is done. I use following to inject:

`junit "*.xml"`

After this stage, in next stage I need number of passed, failed tests etc for comparison.

Comment: I haven't found proper solution for this. I am using workaround - I have added script tag in Jenkinsfile and manually parsing the junit xml file to find the numbers.